# Joining three tables into one using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

Let's say I have 3 tables which is represented by Java classes:

```
ClassRoom {
int id;
int student_id;
int teacher_id;
String name;
}

Student{ 
int id;
String name;
}

Teacher{
int id
String name;
}
```

In my code I would need to use student name and teacher name, but currently I only have their ids, using hibernate I want to eventually get entity like the one below:

```
ClassRoom {
int id 
String name;
String studentName;
String teacherName;
}
```

Should I create a class like that? Or I can do everything using hibernate logic via some of its method to get list of such objects? I assume the task is a common one, but I am new to hibernate, and I can't really find a good search words to find some good examples on web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreignKey.

```
ClassRoom {
 int id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_student"))
 Student student_id;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_teacher"))
 Teacher teacher_id;

 String name;
}
```

Than you can use it as classes, like .getName() or something.
[it's](https://o7planning.org/en/10969/java-hibernate) pretty good tutorial

Comment: Is there a way to get the teacherName, and studentName via only one query? Let's say im calling classRoomRepo.findAll(), I will only get regular ClassRoom entity with Ids instead of names, right? What should I do to get names instead of Ids?

Comment: First option: .getTeacher().getName(), or, you can do in the communicator: use ClassRoom cr=(ClassRoom) session.createQuery("SQL") Here can write an sql with JOIN and NAME column

Answer (score 0):

So, after browsing through several tutorials as well as applying DrHelmholtz advise I'm ended up having the following set up for my classRoom:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"className"})
@ToString(of = {"id", "className", "student", "teacher"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Classroom")
public class ClassRoom {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernateSeq", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernateSeq")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "class_name")
    private String className;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_student"))
    private Student student;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_teacher"))
    private Teacher teacher;

    public ClassRoom(final String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }
}
```

There are several good tips that I would like to point out:

1. I've ditched from using Lombok @Data because it creates hasCode using every single field, which is most of the time is excessive.
2. Performance wise GenerationType.SEQUENCE is the best, because it creates ids in batches (default = 50), not sure if mine was that good, becase I use postgres, which for some reason doesn't work with defaults, I had to set up allocationSize to 1.
3. Lazy Fetch should be default to avoid N+1 problem